# relating to installation of ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: reboot

I just want to reboot my laptop using ubuntu 16.04LTS.After downloading it is showing to burn it to a disc,but I want to do it using a pendrive.How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `dd` command to create a live boot flash drive.

in this example I am going to call the USB pen drive `/dev/sdb1` and the ISO disk image `/home/endrias/ubuntu.ISO`. you need to `umount` the drive before proceeding with the preparation. Here is the command:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
dd if=/home/endrias/ubuntu.ISO of=/dev/sdb1
```

then just restart your computer and plug in your flash drive and boot from USB.

Comment: no i am using a windows 7 laptop

Comment: in that case use the `unetbootin` tool and use it to create a bootable pen drive. It's very easy, you can see how on youtube.

Comment: Not necessarily, if the OP uses EFI use Win32DiskImager or Rufus instead.